# Getting all nodes that have atleast 2 nodes connected to them

Tags: prolog

Having some issues with a Prolog question:

> The following clauses represent a directed graph, where nodes are
>   atoms, and edges are denoted by  the connected predicate. Given that
>   the following clauses are in the database, answer the two questions
>   below.

```
connected(a,b).
connected(b,d).
connected(b,e).
connected(b,f).
connected(a,c).
connected(c,f).
connected(c,g).
connected(h,c).
path(X,Y) :- connected(X,Y).
path(X,Z) :- connected(X,Y), path(Y,Z).
```

> Show the Prolog query that returns all nodes having two or more
>   different incoming edges (i.e., at  least two different nodes are
>   connected to it). Also, show the result of entering the query (asking 
>   for every solution). Your query may return the same node multiple
>   times, and may printout the  values of other variables in the query.
>   The variable denoting the node in question should be  called DNode.

---

So far I have:

```
path(DNode,__) , path(__,DNode).
```

But that only give me *b* and *c*
I think the letters with more than one nodes are *a, b, c, f*.
I tried this to get *a, b* and *c*:

```
path(__,DNode),path(DNode,__) ; path(DNode,__) , path(DNode,__).
```

But I got *a, b, c* and *h*.
I am assuming I'll have to like this to get all the letters I want:

```
path(__,DNode),path(DNode,__) ; path(DNode,__) , path(DNode,__) ; path(__,DNode) , path(__,DNode).
```

It gives me a, b, c, e, f, g and h though.

Any advice about how to get the 4 letters I want would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you display your graph, perhaps with Graphviz

[image]

```
?- writeln('digraph G {'), forall(connected(A,B), writeln(A->B)), writeln('}').
```

you can see that only [c,f] have 2 *incoming* edges, and that you *don't* need path/2. It's sufficient a join on the second argument of connected/2, with a test that the first arguments are different (operator (\=)/2).

Comment: Thank you very much! i thought that since it said in brackets, all edges connected to it, i included a and b. also thanks for the hint about the operator and answer, it gave me the right direction to look in to get my answer. It was confusing at first since i didnt really get your answer.